# Save file to MS SQL with flask + sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, flask, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I have a column i DB which has type IMAGE. I would like to insert binary data to this column. My setup is:

Python 3.6
Flask
sqlalchemy (wit pyodbc)

Here is the scenario:
1. User upload file
2. I take the file and get the data by:

```
file = request.files['file']
data = file.read()
```

3. Insert it

```
conn = self.dbcon.engine.raw_connection()
cursor = conn.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO Documents (FileName, Documentdata)
VALUES('{0}', {1});".format("test.pdf", data)

id = cursor.execute(sql)
```

It seems the query return no error but i cannot see the last insert. Like it never insert or ran the sql.

Did i miss anything?

Comment: First of all: don't pass parameters using string formatting. It seems you're not committing your changes.

Comment: Wow i just missed that "commit". Ok it does save now. But the binary are not correct. It's just a value *1* (should be hex eller binary text?) . I am plan to use store procedures, so this insert is just a test to see why i could save the data

Comment: Thank you Ilja, I managed to save the file after i added `cursor.commit()` . Looks like the raw_connection do not commit by default.